# Split google maps route in few equal segments

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm trying to find a way to split google distance route in few segments and get points of it. Main idea is to get places(from google places service) in between two points. But not for all route, just for few points in between.

I was thinking about RouteBoxer ([Link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html)), but it might be cases, when "box" is very large.

maybe you have any ideas how, after summing route distance, get point in route after some distance? Let say, I have a route that is 1000km in total. And then how to get point on the route in 200km? 500km? 700km? It would be perfect for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [km markers every 2 km on a polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html), [2 markers at specific distances along a route from the directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html) (using Mike Williams' epoly ported to v3 (v3_epoly.js))